# Home Page Catalog Products List Links Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, products

I have added the Home Page Catalog Products List in my home page using the following block xml code

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
</block>
</reference>
```

Here is the front end link: http://70.35.196.150/

In this product list, it was divided into 2 parts. 1st part is "RECOMMENDED FOR YOU" section will scroll.. Those product links are working fine. 
2nd part is some grid view.. Those links are not getting properly..

Here is the reference link: http://70.35.196.150//root-catalog/jain-irrigation-octa-bubbler-10-gph-flow-control-device-red-8-bag.html

See in this links there was //root-catalog/ .. I hope this is problem with the link..

I tried and search for many possibilities but no use..

Thanks

Comment: in magento check backend check url rewrite management

Comment: that particular product rewrite or not

Comment: how can I do it @LearningMagento

Comment: All the products in that gird was having that "//root-catalog" @LearningMagento

Comment: Login your admin panel then goto catalo->url rewrite management check here

Comment: Please share your list.phtml code